# Binding de uma Imagem no Resource do Prejeto

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Bom dia, pessoal.

Eu estou fazendo um app de clima pro curso que estou fazendo e os ícones referentes ao clima puxamos direto de links na internet.

Como eu faria isso localmente?

O Ícone é especificado por uma variável int WeatherIcon.
Eu baixei as imagens, e as coloquei no Resource do projeto com o nome referente ao numero dela na veriável pra facilitar, assim como é no site. Tanto pela internet quando pelo caminho completo da imagem eu apenas coloco a variável no caminho e pronto:
`@"~\..\..\WIcon\" + Condition.WeatherIcon.ToString() + ".png"`

Como eu conseguiria colocar essa imagem que está no resource do projeto, sendo especificada por essa variável, dentro de um picturebox?

**EDIT:**

WeatherVM.cs

```
public Bitmap Icon
    {
        get 
        {
            ResourceManager rm = Resources.ResourceManager;
            Bitmap icone = (Bitmap)rm.GetObject(Condition.WeatherIcon.ToString() + ".png");
            return icone;
        }
        
    }
```

XAML

```
<Image DataContext="{StaticResource vm}"
       Source="{Binding Icon}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o Resource Manager:

```
ResourceManager rm = Resources.ResourceManager;
Bitmap icone = (Bitmap)rm.GetObject(Condition.WeatherIcon.ToString() + ".png");
```

Comment: Fiz isso mas não aparece no designer. Eu editei a pergunta colocando parte do código. O que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Pelas pesquisas que fiz você precisa de um `BitmapImage` ao invés de `Bitmap`. Se você colocar um nome nessa pictureBox, você consegue alterar pelo código mesmo usando `Bitmap`?